# Connecting otel agent with otel collector

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I have followed all the steps mentioned in this medium article: https://medium.com/@guilospanck/telemetry-with-opentelemetry-prometheus-and-jaeger-46a2d9dec86b

My application is supposed to send trace data to collector and collector is supposed to send them to jaeger and prometheus.
[image]

However I am unable to send any traces to the collector. My tracer.properties file has following config:

```
# debugging
#otel.javaagent.debug=true

#prod
otel.traces.exporter=otlp,logging
otel.metrics.exporter=otlp,logging
otel.logs.exporter=none
otel.service.name=service1
#otel.exporter.jaeger.endpoint=http://localhost:14278
#otel.exporter.jaeger.timeout=10000
#otel.propagators=jaeger
otel.exporter.otlp.traces.endpoint=http://localhost:14278
otel.exporter.otlp.metrics.endpoint=http://localhost:14278
otel.exporter.otlp.traces.protocol=grpc
otel.exporter.otlp.metrics.protocol=grpc
```

Whenever I try to send data I get following error:

```
[otel.javaagent 2023-01-03 10:27:00:271 +0530] [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - '/' : ee593fc59976ce74468789cae3dc67d9 6b6a159470d9545b SERVER [tracer: io.opentelemetry.tomcat-10.0:1.20.2-alpha] AttributesMap{data={net.sock.host.addr=127.0.0.1, http.user_agent=Java/17.0.5, http.route=/, http.method=GET, http.scheme=http, net.host.name=localhost, net.transport=ip_tcp, http.status_code=200, net.host.port=8081, http.target=/, net.sock.peer.addr=127.0.0.1, http.flavor=1.1, http.response_content_length=134, thread.name=http-nio-8081-exec-2, thread.id=26, net.sock.peer.port=61816}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=16}
[otel.javaagent 2023-01-03 10:27:04:689 +0530] [OkHttp http://localhost:14278/...] ERROR io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.OkHttpGrpcExporter - Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: FRAME_SIZE_ERROR: 4740180
```

In the medium article author tries to connect a go application but here I try to connect a java application. Other than that there is no change in both of our setup.

I am able to connect directly with jaeger-all-in-one and get trace data (check commented out config in tracer.properties). Issue is connecting via collector

Comment: Pls provide reproducible example (e.g. used otel collector config, ...).

Comment: @JanGaraj the code used is already in that medium article. I have not changed anything and hence for brevity did not add the codes. Please check that article for otel collector config.

Comment: Please refer to this where I have added my partially working configuration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74991374/promethrus-is-not-reading-otel-data