# Prometheus is not reading OTEL data

Tags: java, prometheus, open-telemetry, jaeger

I have configured docker compose for open telemetry collector, prometheus and jaeger and send data via otel agent. Jaeger is working fine but prometheus is not showing any metrics despite collector receiving metrics data.

Following is my configuration:

docker-compose.yml:

```
# docker-compose.yml file
version: "3.5"
services:
  jaeger:
    container_name: jaeger
    hostname: jaeger
    networks:
      - backend
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    volumes:
      - "./jaeger-ui.json:/etc/jaeger/jaeger-ui.json"
    command: --query.ui-config /etc/jaeger/jaeger-ui.json
    environment:
      - METRICS_STORAGE_TYPE=prometheus
      - PROMETHEUS_SERVER_URL=http://prometheus:9090
    ports:
      - "14250:14250"
      - "14268:14268"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "16686:16686"
      - "16685:16685"
  collector:
    container_name: collector
    hostname: collector
    networks:
      - backend
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:latest
    volumes:
      - "./otel-collector-config.yml:/etc/otelcol/otel-collector-config.yml"
    command: --config /etc/otelcol/otel-collector-config.yml
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
      - "6666:6666"
    depends_on:
      - jaeger
  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    hostname: prometheus
    networks:
      - backend
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - "./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
networks:
  backend:
```

otel-collector-config.yml:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5555
processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 1s
    send_batch_size: 1
exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "collector:6666"
  jaeger:
    endpoint: "jaeger:14250" # using the docker-compose name of the jaeger container
    tls:
      insecure: true
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ jaeger ]
    metrics:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ prometheus ]
```

prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 1s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 1s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: collector
    scrape_interval: 1s
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'collector:6666' ] # using the name of the OpenTelemetryCollector container defined in the docker compose file
```

Following is my tracer.properties config used for otel agent for java:

```
otel.traces.exporter=otlp,logging
otel.metrics.exporter=otlp
otel.logs.exporter=none
otel.service.name=service1
otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://0.0.0.0:5555
otel.exporter.otlp.protocol=grpc
otel.traces.sampler=always_on
otel.metric.export.interval=1000
```

I can get trace data in jaeger without any issues:
[image]

However metrics is not working:
[image]

I am also unable to see any metrics data in prometheus:
[image]

What config am I missing for this to work? Also please specify how to optimize this for production.

Comment: this java agent is only available for java based components. hence adding that tag is necessary for this type of question. otherwise this post will be language agnostic which is not the intent.

Answer (score 2):

I've run in the same issue, using the [opentelemetry demo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-demo/tree/471204eec5031dffcb241c143822d7e4905abc75) as base.

It is a bit misleading and confusing (for people like me, who just started with OTEL).

There are multiple `spanmetrics` "plugins" whose produced data is incompatible between them.

- (deprecated) spanmetrics PROCESSOR

  - creates `calls_total` and `latency_bucket`
- (incompatible) spanmetrics CONNECTOR

  - creates `calls` and `duration_bucket`

The PROCESSOR produces data in `prometheus` that is compatible with `jaeger` = my "Monitor" tab in Jaeger UI now shows metrics.

The CONNECTOR uses a new format, which is compatible with the example [Grafana Dashboards](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-demo/blob/471204eec5031dffcb241c143822d7e4905abc75/src/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/general/spanmetrics-dashboard.json#L948) included in the demo folder (thus i don't want to change them).

> it should be possible to change the general exporting format of the CONNECTOR, but how that works... I don't know yet

This config is a bit simplified, see comments for the "what" spanmetrics is used where:

```yaml
receivers:
    otlp:
        protocols:
            grpc:

exporters:
    otlp:
        endpoint: "jaeger:4317"
        tls:
            insecure: true
    logging:
    prometheus:
        # this prometheus is used by `spanmetrics` CONNECTOR + PROCESSOR
        endpoint: "otelcol:9464"
        # these configs apply to the `spanmetrics` CONNECTOR
        resource_to_telemetry_conversion:
            enabled: true
        enable_open_metrics: true # even with `false`, the data wasn't compatible with `jaeger`

processors:
    batch:
    # deprecated spanmetrics PROCESSOR, used for compatibility with Jaeger Metrics
    spanmetrics:
        metrics_exporter: prometheus

connectors:
    # new spanmetrics CONNECTOR
    spanmetrics:

service:
    pipelines:
        traces:
            receivers: [ otlp ]
            processors: [ batch, spanmetrics ] # configuring spanmetrics PROCESSOR (deprecated)
            exporters: [ otlp, spanmetrics ] # configuring spanmetrics CONNECTOR (not compatible w/ jaeger)
        metrics:
            receivers: [ redis, otlp, spanmetrics ] # configuring spanmetrics CONNECTOR as source of "metrics" (not compatible w/ jaeger)
            processors: [ batch ]
            exporters: [ prometheus ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The bind address for the prometheus exporter is `"collector:6666"`. This means that the created server will accept requests only on port `6666` and only from host `collector`. However, the host of Prometheus is different.
It's better to bind to "any address", e.g. `"0.0.0.0:6666"`.

Also, you can use `prometheusremotewrite` exporter instead of `prometheus`. This way you will be able to see problems in the collector logs.

Answer (score -1):

The Monitor tab in Jaeger requires you to set up the [spanmetric processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/processor/spanmetricsprocessor). This processor will look at spans sent to the OpenTelemetry Collector and if the `span.kind` is `server` it will create metrics for the duration of the spans, keep it in memory until Prometheus scrapes the metrics endpoint - typically on port `8889`. The Jaeger UI can then collect these metrics from Prometheus.

Without the spanmetrics processor - You will not be able to see any data in Jaeger's Monitor tab.

Look at the [service performance monitoring documentation](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.41/spm/) on setting up the Monitor tab as it describes these details.